# Word to call a person that works in a store

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I seem to always have a trouble with this one; what do you call a person that works in a store? A clerk? A sales person? Neither of these sound right. Saying "person that works in the store" doesn't work that well either.

Is there a general single word that I can use that represents "a person that works in a store".

Comment: What kind of store do you mean?  Dept store?  Grocery store?  The answer may vary.  Also, many larger stores have cashiers, stockers, and salespersons.

Comment: Just sayin', it should be a person *who* works in a store.

Comment: I remember hearing "floorwalker" as a fairly general term for this, but it may be a dated term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you can't apply any of the fine terms provided here so far:

> ***employee***  will always work.

Comment: Yes!  Or *store employee*, if you need to be more specific.

Comment: I like employee too, but "checkout girl" doesn't sound too bad either. Most of the time we encounter the checkout girl/guy when shopping.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK we have *shop assistant* but there are more specific terms like *checkout girl* and the possibly pejorative *shelf-stacker*, as well as the general *shopworker*, *retail worker* and so on. The best word to use probably depends on what your person actually does.

Answer (score 2):

In Canada we have:

- salespersons who sell you items (we used to have salesmen too),
- cashiers who just work at the cash register and don't assist you in choosing items,
- managers, and
- specialty workers such as butchers, bakers, etc.

So there isn't a single word that would cover all persons working in a store. I suppose salesperson might be the most common position.

Answer (score 2):

I think *clerk* is fairly general.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are looking for the word "associate."

According to [Merriam-Webster's 3rd entry for 'associate" (noun)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/associate):

> 2.b. employee, worker

This is often used in conjunction with a modifier to make it more specific, such as:

> Sales Associate, Retail Associate, etc.

but is frequently used by itself as well.

> "I'm waiting for an associate to check the storeroom for my size."